# Can I publish multiple artifacts on single artifactId?

Tags: maven, gradle

I know how to publish single artifact using single `artifactId`. I am using gradle to publish my artifacts. My artifacts are .aar files.
I publish my artifact like this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example.project'
            version '1.0.2'
            artifactId 'myProject'
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/mySDK-release.aar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Now I want to publish multiple artifacts using single `artifactId`.

Comment: So how do you want to distinguish them? By classifier?

Comment: Yes, I can use classifiers to distinguish them.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Use the classifiers.

---

Since you're publishing to Maven, let's read their docs about [Maven Coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#maven-coordinates):

> The POM defined above is the bare minimum that Maven allows.
>   `groupId:artifactId:version` are all required fields (although, groupId
>   and version do not need to be explicitly defined if they are inherited
>   from a parent - more on inheritance later). The three fields act much
>   like an address and timestamp in one. This marks a specific place in a
>   repository, acting like a coordinate system for Maven projects:
>
> - **groupId**: This is generally unique amongst an organization or a project. For example, all core Maven artifacts do (well, should) live
>     under the groupId `org.apache.maven`. Group ID's do not necessarily use
>     the dot notation, for example, the junit project. Note that the
>     dot-notated groupId does not have to correspond to the package
>     structure that the project contains. It is, however, a good practice
>     to follow. When stored within a repository, the group acts much like
>     the Java packaging structure does in an operating system. The dots are
>     replaced by OS specific directory separators (such as '/' in Unix)
>     which becomes a relative directory structure from the base repository.
>     In the example given, the `org.codehaus.mojo` group lives within the
>     directory `$M2_REPO/org/codehaus/mojo`.
> - **artifactId**: The artifactId is generally the name that the project is known by. Although the groupId is important, people within the
>     group will rarely mention the groupId in discussion (they are often
>     all be the same ID, such as the [MojoHaus](http://www.mojohaus.org/) project groupId:
>     `org.codehaus.mojo`). It, along with the groupId, creates a key that
>     separates this project from every other project in the world (at
>     least, it should :) ). Along with the groupId, the artifactId fully
>     defines the artifact's living quarters within the repository. In the
>     case of the above project, `my-project` lives in
>     `$M2_REPO/org/codehaus/mojo/my-project`.
> - **version**: This is the last piece of the naming puzzle. `groupId:artifactId` denotes a single project but they cannot delineate
>     which incarnation of that project we are talking about. Do we want the
>     `junit:junit` of 2018 (version 4.12), or of 2007 (version 3.8.2)? In
>     short: code changes, those changes should be versioned, and this
>     element keeps those versions in line. It is also used within an
>     artifact's repository to separate versions from each other. `my-project`
>     version 1.0 files live in the directory structure
>     `$M2_REPO/org/codehaus/mojo/my-project/1.0`.
>
> The three elements given above point to a specific version of a
>   project, letting Maven know who we are dealing with, and when in its
>   software lifecycle we want them.

It's clear that Maven Coordinates is a unique identifier of a specific version of an artifact. There may be no two different artifacts with the same coordinates.

The only way to publish two artifacts under single `artifactId` is to use different versions.

If you check the [version order specs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#version-order-specification), you'll see that you can use so called qualifiers, like `1.0.0-ALPHA`, `1.0.0-RC`. That's actually the way javadocs and sources are published in Maven repositories: an artifact with the coordinates `a.b.c:d:1.0.0` may have javadocs published under `a.b.c:d:1.0.0-javadoc` and sources under `a.b.c:d:1.0.0-sources`.

So, use the qualifiers to do the trick.

Qualifiers are specified on the artifacts side in Gradle:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example.project'
            version '1.0.2'
            artifactId 'myProject'


            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/mySDK-release-2.aar") {
                // These values can also be specified in the task that generates the AAR.
                classifier "q1"
            }
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/mySDK-release-1.aar") {
                classifier "q2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great knowledge.